# Spring - RequestMapping default method documentation ambiguity/confusion?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, request-mapping

From [Spring Framework Reference `5.2.7.RELEASE`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-head-options):

> For a `@RequestMapping` without HTTP method declarations, the `Allow`
>   header is set to `GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS`.

Which certainly meets our day-to-day coding experiences.

But, in *Spring Framework API Documentation [`5.2.7.RELEASE`]* of [`RequestMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html):

The default value for the element [`method`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#method--) is presented as

> **Default:**
>
> `{}`

I am confused by this. What am I missing here?

Comment: Both are right. The `method` is used to limit it to those defined. If nothing is defined, everything is allowed (which is what is being expressed explicitly in the reference guide).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`method`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#method--) argument can be used to **limit** the accepted HTTP methods. The default is that there is **no limit**. So by default it allows all HTTP methods.

Now this is exactly what [the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-head-options) is telling you.

> For a `@RequestMapping` without HTTP method declarations, the `Allow` header is set to `GET`,`HEAD`,`POST`,`PUT`,`PATCH`,`DELETE`,`OPTIONS`.

There is no `method` declaration to limit it, hence everything is accepted.

Comment: Oh exactly! The `Allow` header is actually being set on the basis of the value(s) provided to the `method` element of `RequestMapping`. Looking at the docs side by side made me confused. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following example

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = "/collect_list", method = {RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET})
```

Comment: Appreciate your effort. But unfortunately this doesn't attempt to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

That means there is not default method, so you have to explicitly declare it on your function which one do you want to use. If not, all type of request will hit that endpoint.
So it is not a good practice to leave it empty. You can use `@GetMapping` etc instead, which is for example a sortcut to `@RequestMapping(value = "/myurl", method = {RequestMethod.GET})`.
It may a little confusing at first, but if you declare as empty, then it is better choice to recieve all request then none of them. I think that was the logic behind it.